# AppEngine BigQuery PHP libraries not implicit in runtime?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am trying to make a BigQuery call from PHP on AppEngine.  Is one to assume that the BigQuery PHP libraries must be included in the deployment files and they are not implicitly available in the runtime?

Simple instantiation example:

```
<?php
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient();
?>
```

And then the inevitable error:

```
[error] 20#20: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient' not found in /srv/index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /srv/index.php on line 3" while reading response header from upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/google-config/php-fpm.sock:"
```

Is the expectation that these libs would be implicit too assumptive?

Edit: here is the `composer.json` file that is in the deploy directory (of which I'm terribly confused as the `app.yaml` should be declarative location for libs, no?)

I'm not even sure how to specify versions or just BQ in general.

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud": "^0.99.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your composer.json file? Did you added there the BQ library?

Comment: @Pentium10 maybe therein lies the rub.  Admittedly I'm a bit lost on this composer thing, but question updated with that file.

Comment: composer looks fine, make sure that in your php files you include vendor/autoload.php

Comment: @Pentium10, thanks, do the vendor/* files need to be included in the deployment package?  Also, does one assume said directory is in the CWD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is one to assume that the BigQuery PHP libraries must be included in
>   the deployment files and they are not implicitly available in the
>   runtime?

That's correct, you should use the **BigQuery** [**PHP client library**](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php).

See the information on its **installation** and **usage** in this [**article**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api) of Google Cloud Platform documentation *(switch to "PHP" tab for a code sample)*.

**EDIT:**

I have replicated your situation by following a GCP [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/quickstart) to deploy a simple PHP HelloWorld app to Google App Engine. I have modified the **composer.json** file so that it would match yours and used the same lines of code to include the BigQuery library.

I could solve the issue by **requiring Composer's autoloader**. This can be achieved by adding the following line to the **index.php** file:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Here's my **composer.json** file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud": "^0.99.0"
    }
}
```

Here's my **index.php** file:

```
<?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
  $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient();

  echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you.  I have the PHP libs, question is if they need to be bundled with the files for deployment or if they are implicitly included in the PHP AppEngine runtime.

Comment: The cloud client library is not implicitly installed on app engine. With that said, you don't need to explicitly deploy the vendor directory as we will run `composer install` on your behalf as long as a composer.json file is available.